# Converting Spring Boot Sample JNDI to work in separate Tomcat instance

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, jndi

I did `git clone` on the [Spring Boot Sample JNDI app](https://github.com/wilkinsona/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jndi) on Github, ran it in embedded mode at it works OK.

So, now I want to convert it to run on a separate Tomcat instance.

Firstly, I changed the pom.xml packaging to `war`.

Secondly, I changed `SampleTomcatJndiApplication` class to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` add added the following method:

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(SampleTomcatJndiApplication.class);
}
```

I also changed the JNDI properties. The Tomcat instance (Tomcat 8.0.24) has the following context defined in server.xml:

```
    <Resource auth="Container" 
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    maxActive="8" maxIdle="4" 
    name="jdbc/finance" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/finance" 
    username="xxxx" password="yyyy" />
```

My DataSource bean is defined as

```
@Bean(destroyMethod="")
public DataSource jndiDataSource() throws IllegalArgumentException, NamingException {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    bean.setJndiName("java:comp/env/jdbc/finance");
    bean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
    bean.setLookupOnStartup(false);
    bean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return (DataSource)bean.getObject();
}
```

When running on an existing Tomcat instance, I always get this exception:

Name [jdbc/finance] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].

When running in embedded mode, it works OK.

How can I get this to work on an existing Tomcat ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in my application at all, but in my Tomcat configuration. Thanks to the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545169/name-jdbc-mydb-is-not-bound-in-this-context), I found out that I needed to add a ResourceLink element to Tomcat's context.xml. I wonder why the Tomcat JNDI HowTo makes no mention of it?