# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/mydb] is not bound in this Context

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7, jndi, ibm-midrange

I know this question has been asked several times. I found some links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545169/name-jdbc-mydb-is-not-bound-in-this-context) and [here](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/4556736) as an example of what I found. But I try their solutions and my problem is not solved yet...

So I copy what I have:

- A J2EE project in Eclipse. I built a new .war to install in an application server
- I created a `Tomcat 7 Server` in Eclipse and added my .war to it to deploy it locally

So phisically in my project I have  a `.war` project and the `Servers` project that auto-creates when you create a new Server in Eclipse.

I tried to connect to a local `as400 db` but when I did so, I found this error:

```
Error com.myprojectpackage.xxx: Name XXX is not bound in this Context
```

I tried to add a `ResourceLink` as said in one of the links I attach:

```
 <ResourceLink name="jdbc/mydb"
         global="jdbc/mydb"
         type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

First I tried to create it in my application like this:

1. In my `web.xml`

   `<resource-ref> 
        <description>Datasource for my db</description> 
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/mydb</res-ref-name> 
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type> 
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth> 
   </resource-ref>`
2. I created a custom `context.xml` file and added

`<ResourceLink name="jdbc/mydb" 
             global="jdbc/mydb" 
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
               username="myuser" password="mypass" auth="Container" 
               driverClassName="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver" url="jdbc:as400://192.168.1.1;naming=system;errors=full;" />`

This first try didn't work. So I went to the server side, and added the following:

1. In `context.xml` file:

`<ResourceLink name="jdbc/mydb" 
             global="jdbc/mydb" 
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
               username="myuser" password="mypass" auth="Container" 
               driverClassName="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver" url="jdbc:as400://192.168.1.1;naming=system;errors=full;" />`

2. In `server.xml` I added the same `ResourceLink` inside `Context`

This second try failed too.

So, what the problem is? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first approach failed because you must provide a factory class for your DataSource, so that Tomcat be aware how to create connection, what driver to use and so on.

The second one failed because of not properly used *ResourceLink* element.

As stated in the Tomcat's documentation:

> This element is used to create a link to a global JNDI resource.

Instead, you should create the following declaration into the **META-INF/context.xml** file:

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/mydb"
              global="jdbc/mydb" 
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" 
              maxWait="10000" 
              username="myuser" password="mypass" auth="Container" 
              driverClassName="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver" 
              url="jdbc:as400://192.168.1.1;naming=system;errors=full;"/>
</Context>
```

Then make sure the META-INF folder located at the proper place - you must include it within */webapp* folder of your ***.war*** package.

Now you can refer to your DataSource through *JNDI* by using the following name:

**"java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb"**