# Issue in starting Tomcat after migrating to Tomcat 9 from Tomcat 7

Tags: oracle, tomcat

I have upgraded Tomcat from 7 to 9. I am getting exception while start up. It is throwing below exception:

**oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource cannot be cast to java.sql.Driver**

context.xml has following :

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource" 
        logAbandoned="true" initialSize="1" maxActive="2" maxIdle="2" 
        minIdle="2" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="34000" 
        inEvictableIdleTimeMillis="55000" validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" 
        validationInterval="34" testOnBorrow="true" removeAbandoned="true" 
        removeAbandonedTimeout="600" name="jdbc/regionalDS" password="XXX" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOSTURL" 
        username="XXX" />
```

Please let me know, what changes I need to do.

Comment: I am still getting Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/regionalDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]. All configuration I have verified.

Answer (score 2):

Two things you can try :
1. Change the `type` to `type="javax.sql.XADataSource"`
2. Check that the url is in the form of `url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@your_host_name:port_say_1521:service_or_sid"`

Comment: I have changed 1 as suggested. I am now getting this exception:

Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/regionalDS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].

Comment: Glad it fixed the original issue you posted.

Comment: For the second issue, take a look at this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545169/name-jdbc-mydb-is-not-bound-in-this-context